# Insert 2 items in separate tables EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, .net-core

I'm making a booking application in NETCore.
A booking has a one-to-many relation with occupancy.
Both models have the navigational properties.
It seems like the Foreign key (`OccupancyId`) doesn't get set in `Booking`.

**EDIT:**  Following code seems to work just fine.

```
Occupancy newOccupancy = new Occupancy { AccommodationId = 12, DateIn = new DateTime(2017, 1, 18), DateOut = new DateTime(2017, 2, 18) };
ApplicationDbContext.Occupancies.Add(newOccupancy);
Booking newBooking = new Booking { AccommodationId = 12, BookingStatusId = 6, Capacity = 69, OccupancyId = newOccupancy.Id, Paid = true, ProfileId = 1, Remark = "Geen", Total = 0 };
ApplicationDbContext.Bookings.Add(newBooking);
```

However, when using this code instead, it no longer seems to work

```
ApplicationDbContext.Occupancies.Add(model.Occupancy);
ApplicationDbContext.Bookings.Add(model.Booking);
```

**Create method inside BookingController**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CityViewModel model)
{
    var alert = new Alert();
    try
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid) {
            alert.Message = alert.ExceptionMessage = ApplicationDbContextMessage.INVALID;
            throw new Exception();
        }

        Occupancy newOccupancy = new Occupancy { AccommodationId = 12, DateIn = new DateTime(2017, 1, 18), DateOut = new DateTime(2017, 2, 18) };
        ApplicationDbContext.Occupancies.Add(newOccupancy);
        Booking newBooking = new Booking { AccommodationId = 12, BookingStatusId = 6, Capacity = 69, OccupancyId = newOccupancy.Id, Paid = true, ProfileId = 1, Remark = "Geen", Total = 0 };
        ApplicationDbContext.Bookings.Add(newBooking);

        if (await ApplicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync() == 0)
        {
            alert.Message = alert.ExceptionMessage = ApplicationDbContextMessage.CREATENOK;
            throw new Exception();
        }  

        alert.Message = ApplicationDbContextMessage.CREATEOK;
        alert.Type = AlertType.Success;
        AddAlert(alert);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        alert.Type = AlertType.Error;
        alert.ExceptionMessage = ex.Message;
        //AddAlert(alert);

        model = await ViewModel(model.City);
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, alert.ExceptionMessage);
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

**BookingViewModel**

```
public class BookingViewModel
{
    public Booking Booking { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Accommodations { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> BookingStatuses { get; set; }
    public Occupancy Occupancy { get; set; }
}
```

**Occupancy Model**

```
public class Occupancy : BaseEntity<Int64>
{
    public DateTime DateIn { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOut { get; set; }
    public OccupancyType OccupancyType { get; set; }

    public Int64 AccommodationId { get; set; }
    public Accommodation Accommodation { get; set; }
    public Booking Booking { get; set; }
}
```

**Booking Model**

```
public class Booking : BaseEntity<Int64>
{
    public int Capacity { get; set; }
    public bool Paid { get; set; }
    public Decimal Total { get; set; }
    public string Remark { get; set; }

    public Int64 ProfileId { get; set; }
    public Profile Profile { get; set; }
    public Int64 AccommodationId { get; set; }
    public Accommodation Accommodation { get; set; }
    public Int64 OccupancyId { get; set; }
    public Occupancy Occupancy { get; set; }
    public Int64 BookingStatusId { get; set; }
    public BookingStatus BookingStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have resolved this by using this in my Controller

```
ApplicationDbContext.Occupancies.Add(model.Occupancy);
model.Booking.OccupancyId = model.Occupancy.Id;
ApplicationDbContext.Bookings.Add(model.Booking);
```

So I think something is wrong with the navigational properties, not sure what, but this seem to be fixing things for now.

Answer (score 2):

This might help: 
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Your key can be defined by using data annotations, and putting the virtual keyword infront of the Country, like so:

```
[ForeignKey("Country")]
public Int16 CountryID { get; set; }
public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
```

you also need to add a `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;`.

Comment: I think the problem is more at the Controller itself rather than wrong mapping.

Comment: Thank you for the update, glad to hear that your method worked!